# Docker: Mongo exits on run

Tags: mongodb, docker, boot2docker

Using:

```
https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mongo/
```

I did this to pull in all tags:

```
docker pull mongo
```

Then, when I try to run it with

```
docker run -v /data:/data --name mongodb -p 4000:27017 mongo:2.6.6
```

The status shows

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
5959d3f79243        mongo:2.6.6         "/entrypoint.sh mong   4 seconds ago       Exited (1) 3 seconds ago                            mongodb
```

Logs show:

```
numactl: This system does not support NUMA policy
```

How do I keep mongo running while using docker? I am using Docker 1.4.1 on OSX (boot2docker).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the boot2docker VM doesn't support NUMA, and the current Dockerfile [executes mongod through `numactl`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/75750813f758b32adbaba02fb391660d42cbcc1a/2.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L10). A possible workaround:

```
$ docker run -v /data:/data --name mongodb -p 4000:27017 --entrypoint=mongod mongo:2.6.6
```

This uses [`--entrypoint`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) to override the image defined `ENTRYPOINT` and execute `mongod` directly.